# What is "link to executable"?

Tags: symbolic-link

What is "link to executable" ? I'm trying to understand what "gcc" is. If I open Properties of it in Unity UI it says "link to executable".

I googled it. Tried following commands

link
readlink
ln

I'm confused. What command I should use in order to:

- check whether file is link or not
- view where link points to
- change destination of a link (I need to repoint `gcc` to `gcc 4.7` in my case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a symbolic link, created with the `ln` command. To replace the link, you need to do

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

or

```
sudo ln -sf `which gcc` `which gcc-4.7`
```

The -s is for symbolic (otherwise you will get a "hard link"), -f is for "force", because the target already exists.

I assume that you **do have gcc-4.7 installed**, and that there is a binary in /usr/bin called "gcc-4.7". Ootherwise you will only break your existing link.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, figured this out

`sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: What's the significance of `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me while i was inside the same folder

```
User@COMPUTER:/opt/Prepros-linux-64$ sudo ln -s Prepros /usr/bin/prepros
```

*Didn't work*

```
User@COMPUTER:~$ sudo ln -s /opt/Prepros-linux-64/Prepros /usr/bin/prepros
```

*It worked*

I hope it helps someone else.